# How to fix 'All Hibernate caches should be created upfront. Please update CacheConfiguration.java to add com.nissan.rca.domain.OCIOMacroTypeOfService'

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, caching, jhipster

I am fairly new to JHipster and the technology that it uses.  A project that I have joined recently was made using JHipster with spring-boot, hibernate, liquidbase, maven and angular 4.  I took it on myself to upgrade the project (since a lot of the technologies were outdated versions) and I have got stuck trying to solve this error.
I don't know much about caching at all and don't really know what the config files do, however I believe that the errors lie in the DatabaseConfiguration.java and CacheConfiguration.java files.

I receive this error after running the backend with `mvn spring-boot:run`

I'm not sure what to try or how to fix this, however I had a look in CacheConfiguration.java and found that the class which it is telling me to add (com.nissan.rca.domain.OCIOMacroTypeOfService) for caching is already added to the cache manager.

This is the error:

```
2019-02-07 14:58:20.013  WARN 9392 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.spri
ngframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error cr
eating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$Web
MvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to ins
tantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.fa
ctory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditEventsEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/audit/AuditEventsEndp
ointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'auditEventsEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyEx
ception: Error creating bean with name 'customAuditEventRepository' defined in file [D:\RCA\ResourceCalenderApplication\target\classes\com\nissan\rca\repository\CustomAuditEventRepository.cl
ass]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenc
eAuditEventRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1411479e' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1411479e': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while set
ting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [o
rg/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit
: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: All Hibernate caches should be created upfront. Please update CacheConfiguration.jav
a to add com.nissan.rca.domain.OCIOMacroTypeOfService
2019-02-07 14:58:20.270 ERROR 9392 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

Here is CacheConfiguration.java

```
package com.nissan.rca.config;
import java.time.Duration;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.*;
import org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107Configuration;
import io.github.jhipster.config.jcache.BeanClassLoaderAwareJCacheRegionFactory;
import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureAfter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureBefore;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.JCacheManagerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
// @AutoConfigureAfter(value = { MetricsConfiguration.class })
@AutoConfigureBefore(value = { WebConfigurer.class, DatabaseConfiguration.class })
public class CacheConfiguration {

    private final javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Object, Object> jcacheConfiguration;

    public CacheConfiguration(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        BeanClassLoaderAwareJCacheRegionFactory.setBeanClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        JHipsterProperties.Cache.Ehcache ehcache =
            jHipsterProperties.getCache().getEhcache();

        jcacheConfiguration = Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(
            CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Object.class, Object.class,
                ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(ehcache.getMaxEntries()))
                .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.ofSeconds(ehcache.getTimeToLiveSeconds())))
                .build());
    }

    @Bean
    public JCacheManagerCustomizer cacheManagerCustomizer() {
        return cm -> {
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.repository.UserRepository.USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE, jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.repository.UserRepository.USERS_BY_EMAIL_CACHE, jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.User.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Authority.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.User.class.getName() + ".authorities", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ResourceEngagement.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ResourceEngagement.class.getName() + ".ongoingResourceBudgetings", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ResourceEngagement.class.getName() + ".projectResourceBudgetings", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Resource.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Resource.class.getName() + ".resourceEngagements", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ResourceEngagementType.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ResourceEngagementType.class.getName() + ".resourceEngagements", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.EVPLevel.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.EVPLevel.class.getName() + ".resourceEngagements", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Vendor.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Vendor.class.getName() + ".resourceEngagements", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.TechnologyPlatform.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.TechnologyPlatform.class.getName() + ".resourceEngagements", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Role.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Role.class.getName() + ".resourceEngagements", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Section.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Section.class.getName() + ".resourceEngagements", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Location.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Location.class.getName() + ".resourceEngagements", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.OCIOTechnologySoftware.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.OCIOTechnologySoftware.class.getName() + ".resourceEngagements", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.OCIOTypeOfService.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.OCIOTypeOfService.class.getName() + ".resourceEngagements", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.OCIOMacroTypeOfService.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.OCIOMacroTypeOfService.class.getName() + ".oCIOTypeOfServices", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Currency.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Currency.class.getName() + ".resourceEngagements", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Currency.class.getName() + ".currencyExchangeToEuros", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.UserAccess.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.UserAccess.class.getName() + ".resources", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.FinancialYear.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.FinancialYear.class.getName() + ".currencyExchangeToEuros", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.FinancialYear.class.getName() + ".projectBudgets", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.FinancialYear.class.getName() + ".ongoingBudgets", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Project.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Project.class.getName() + ".projectBudgets", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.OngoingBudget.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.OngoingBudget.class.getName() + ".ongoingResourceBudgetings", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.OngoingBudget.class.getName() + ".ongoingSpendItems", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ValueType.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ValueType.class.getName() + ".ongoingResourceBudgetings", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ValueType.class.getName() + ".ongoingSpendItems", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ValueType.class.getName() + ".projectResourceBudgetings", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ValueType.class.getName() + ".projectSpendItems", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.SpendType.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.SpendType.class.getName() + ".ongoingResourceBudgetings", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.SpendType.class.getName() + ".ongoingSpendItems", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.SpendType.class.getName() + ".projectResourceBudgetings", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.SpendType.class.getName() + ".projectSpendItems", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Month.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Month.class.getName() + ".ongoingResourceBudgetings", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Month.class.getName() + ".ongoingSpendItems", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Month.class.getName() + ".projectResourceBudgetings", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.Month.class.getName() + ".projectSpendItems", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ProjectBudget.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ProjectBudget.class.getName() + ".projectResourceBudgetings", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ProjectBudget.class.getName() + ".projectSpendItems", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.CostCentre.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.CostCentre.class.getName() + ".projects", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.CostCentre.class.getName() + ".ongoingBudgets", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ProjectPhase.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ProjectPhase.class.getName() + ".projects", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.CurrencyExchangeToEuro.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.SpendItem.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.SpendItem.class.getName() + ".ongoingSpendItems", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.SpendItem.class.getName() + ".projectSpendItems", jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.OngoingResourceBudgeting.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.OngoingSpendItem.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ProjectSpendItem.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            cm.createCache(com.nissan.rca.domain.ProjectResourceBudgeting.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            // jhipster-needle-ehcache-add-entry
        };
    }
}
```

Here is the DatabseConfiguration.java

```
package com.nissan.rca.config;

import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterConstants;
import io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase;

import liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.nissan.rca.repository")
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfiguration.class);

    private final Environment env;

    public DatabaseConfiguration(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    /**
     * Open the TCP port for the H2 database, so it is available remotely.
     *
     * @return the H2 database TCP server
     * @throws SQLException if the server failed to start
     */
    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    @Profile(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT)
    public Object h2TCPServer() throws SQLException {
        try {
            // We don't want to include H2 when we are packaging for the "prod" profile and won't
            // actually need it, so we have to load / invoke things at runtime through reflection.
            ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            Class<?> serverClass = Class.forName("org.h2.tools.Server", true, loader);
            Method createServer = serverClass.getMethod("createTcpServer", String[].class);
            return createServer.invoke(null, new Object[] { new String[] { "-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers" } });

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | LinkageError  e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load and initialize org.h2.tools.Server", e);

        } catch (SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get method org.h2.tools.Server.createTcpServer()", e);

        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to invoke org.h2.tools.Server.createTcpServer()", e);

        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Throwable t = e.getTargetException();
            if (t instanceof SQLException) {
                throw (SQLException) t;
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Unchecked exception in org.h2.tools.Server.createTcpServer()", t);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase(@Qualifier("taskExecutor") TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
            DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {

        // Use liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase if you don't want Liquibase to start asynchronously
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new AsyncSpringLiquibase(taskExecutor, env);
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml");
        liquibase.setContexts(liquibaseProperties.getContexts());
        liquibase.setDefaultSchema(liquibaseProperties.getDefaultSchema());
        liquibase.setDropFirst(liquibaseProperties.isDropFirst());
        if (env.acceptsProfiles(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_NO_LIQUIBASE)) {
            liquibase.setShouldRun(false);
        } else {
            liquibase.setShouldRun(liquibaseProperties.isEnabled());
            log.debug("Configuring Liquibase");
        }
        return liquibase;
    }
}
```

And here is the class which is shown in the error, OCIOMacroTypeOfService.java

```
package com.nissan.rca.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * A OCIOMacroTypeOfService.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "ociomacrotypeofservice")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class OCIOMacroTypeOfService implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ocio_macro_type_code")
    private String ocioMacroTypeOfServiceCode;

    @Column(name = "ocio_macro_type_description")
    private String ocioMacroTypeDescription;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ocioMacroTypeOfService")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<OCIOTypeOfService> oCIOTypeOfServices = new HashSet<>();
    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
    public String getOcioMacroTypeOfServiceCode() {
        return ocioMacroTypeOfServiceCode;
    }

    public void setOcioMacroTypeOfServiceCode(String ocioMacroTypeOfServiceCode) {
        this.ocioMacroTypeOfServiceCode = ocioMacroTypeOfServiceCode;
    }

    public String getOcioMacroTypeOfServiceDescription() {
        return ocioMacroTypeDescription;
    }

    public OCIOMacroTypeOfService ocioMacroTypeOfServiceDescription(String ocioMacroTypeDescription) {
        this.ocioMacroTypeDescription = ocioMacroTypeDescription;
        return this;
    }

    public void setOcioMacroTypeOfServiceDescription(String ocioMacroTypeDescription) {
        this.ocioMacroTypeDescription = ocioMacroTypeDescription;
    }

    public Set<OCIOTypeOfService> getOCIOTypeOfServices() {
        return oCIOTypeOfServices;
    }

    public OCIOMacroTypeOfService oCIOTypeOfServices(Set<OCIOTypeOfService> oCIOTypeOfServices) {
        this.oCIOTypeOfServices = oCIOTypeOfServices;
        return this;
    }

    public OCIOMacroTypeOfService addOCIOTypeOfService(OCIOTypeOfService oCIOTypeOfService) {
        this.oCIOTypeOfServices.add(oCIOTypeOfService);
        oCIOTypeOfService.setOcioMacroTypeOfService(this);
        return this;
    }

    public OCIOMacroTypeOfService removeOCIOTypeOfService(OCIOTypeOfService oCIOTypeOfService) {
        this.oCIOTypeOfServices.remove(oCIOTypeOfService);
        oCIOTypeOfService.setOcioMacroTypeOfService(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setOCIOTypeOfServices(Set<OCIOTypeOfService> oCIOTypeOfServices) {
        this.oCIOTypeOfServices = oCIOTypeOfServices;
    }
    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here, do not remove

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        OCIOMacroTypeOfService oCIOMacroTypeOfService = (OCIOMacroTypeOfService) o;
        if (oCIOMacroTypeOfService.getOcioMacroTypeOfServiceCode() == null || getOcioMacroTypeOfServiceCode() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getOcioMacroTypeOfServiceCode(), oCIOMacroTypeOfService.getOcioMacroTypeOfServiceCode());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getOcioMacroTypeOfServiceCode());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OCIOMacroTypeOfService{" +
            "ocioMacroTypeOfServiceCode=" + getOcioMacroTypeOfServiceCode() +
            ", ocioMacroTypeOfServiceDescription='" + getOcioMacroTypeOfServiceDescription() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to update a copy of your project using `jhipster upgrade`?

Comment: Unfortunately that’s how I got into this mess. It upgraded 2 versions and so while merging the updated files back in, caused merge conflicts and errors in around 200 files (almost went insane fixing them).  Now this seems to be the last thing but I’m unsure whether it’s a dependancy issue in my pom or a more core problem.

Comment: Are you sure this error is the first one in logs? It could be a consequence of an earlier error as it was for this user https://github.com/hipster-labs/generator-jhipster-entity-audit/issues/60

Comment: Unfortunately it does seem that this is the first error in the logs.  I have checked through thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line and it's will works:

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
```

for example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tablename")
//@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class ClassName implements Serializable{
```